# Inject generics in guice with typeliteral but typeliteral constructor is protected

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, guice

I have started learning guice and stumbled upon using guice to inject generic types. All the solutions in the net seems to use something like `new TypeLiteral<Generic<Type>>(){}`. However, when I'm trying to do this, it shows that constructor of `TypeLiteral` is protected. How can I perform generic injection using `TypeLiteral.get()`? Sample code:

```
public interface Repository<T> {
  void save(T item);
  T get(int id);
}

public StringRepository implements Repository<String> {
  @Override
  public void save(String item) {
    // do saving

  }
 @Override
 public String get(int id) {
   // get item and return
   return item;
 }
}

public MyModule extends AbstractModule{
   @Override
   public void configure() {
      ....
    TypeLiteral<Repository<String>> typeLiteral =
                  TypeLiteral.get((Repository<String>.class));//does not work

    //does not work either because constructor is protected
    bind(new TypeLiteral<Repository<String>>(){}).to(StringRepository.class); 

}

}
```

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

Comment: "does not work either because constructor is protected" protected means it is accessible to subclasses, so it should be accessible. I mean, this is exactly how the documentation says to use it...

Comment: I was fairly sure it worked too, so I tried, and it does. What exactly are you seeing which makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Your screenshot is completely different from the code in the question. It won’t work without the {}

Answer (score 3):

Your text says `new TypeLiteral<Generic<Type>>(){}`. Your screenshot says `new TypeLiteral<Generic<Type>>()`. The first has `{}` at the end, the second does not. Those curly braces are critical - they change the expression from creating a new instance of `TypeLiteral` to *creating an anonymous subclass of* `TypeLiteral` and creating an instance of that subclass.

This is necessary to work around generic type erasure. For the `TypeLiteral` to serve its purpose, it must know at runtime what the generic type arguments are. Type erasure means that a simple instance of a generic class does not know at runtime what its type arguments are. A class that inherits from a generic class does know at runtime what type arguments it used in the inheritance, however. That is:

```
// <String> is erased at run time.
new ArrayList<String>();

// <String> is preserved at run time, as part of the class's information.
class MyList extends ArrayList<String> { }

// A class identical to MyList is created, except without the name, and an instance of that class is created.
new ArrayList<String>(){};
```

Comment: This is a really good explanation of why {} is needed. I’ll upvote if you replace List with ArrayList or something. List is an interface so you can’t write extends List or new List().

Comment: @cppbeginner Apparently I've been doing too much C# work lately, where `List` is the class and the interface is `IList`. Fixed.